# Minimum Height for Vent Pipe

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, pvc

Is there a minimum height for the the vent pipe circled in the image?

[image: drain vent pipe height]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, the horizontal vent branch immediately to the upper left of your red circle cannot turn horizontal until it is a minimum of 6" above the flood rim of the fixture it is attached to or the highest fixture in a group that it is venting.

This will determine the length of the pipe you circled.

Good luck!