# Is there a rule about minimum rise of a vent pipe before it can run horizontal?

Tags: pipe, vent, drain-waste-vent

I am replacing my shower/bath, including removing the wall that houses the vent pipe (the new unit is free-standing). To make the repiping easier, I want to redirect the tub vent pipe to merge with the vent stack for the double sink, which is about 7 feet away. My plan is for the tub vent pipe to start vertical, then almost immediately turn to run horizontal for that 7 feet, then vertical again (with some maneuvering) to merge into the vent stack for the sinks. I know vent pipes can be run horizontal as long as there is a slope, but is there a rule about minimum rise distance of a vent pipe before it can run horizontal?

Comment: Please consider [merging your unregistered and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The vent can't run horizontal until you've reached the overflow height of the attached fixtures.   The idea is you don't want the water to backup into a horizontal section of venting and deposit debris in the event that the waste pipe clogs.  If the waste pipe clogs then the fixture should overflow before water runs into a horizontal section of vent pipe.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/87312/minimum-height-for-vent-pipe

Comment: Thanks! Assuming the overflow of a tub is the overflow opening within the tub (well above the floor), I'm having a tough time thinking of a solution. There aren't any interior walls close enough to put a vent that would be within 5-6 feet of the p-trap, at least not without going through an LVL beam. I could put it in an exterior wall--since it's a vent pipe and expected to stay mostly dry, maybe it wouldn't be a big deal. Any recommendations?

Comment: If your tub drain is 4" pipe it can wet vent as long as it is at most 120" from the stack assuming the stack vents upwards and that your stack is currently 4" pipe.  If you do 3" pipe you can wet vent 72" so 6'.  https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/8Rsv4-0NPvqEF8xgdqcAtge-7SGi3_ar2GNV3UKWyVPiykHdvQ_RmiFMU55cdzyMOtCufewpI1Nm3xi_kZhiXNkMIPnV5x9xEAE_EheymnUYG-0_OojkGSo_uCivmZkx6K3589wZ

Comment: maybe you can do an island vent, the vent pipe only has to climb to overflow height, after that it can go downwards.